# How can I access a different object collection in a view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm not sure how to search for this answer, so I'll go ahead and ask it.

In my rails project I have a User model and a foo model. A user can have one or more foo models assigned to it. I have accomplished this by adding

```
has_many :foo, :through => :user_foo
```

in my user model.

Now, over in my view, I want to display a list of all foos. Not just the ones that are selected (i will be making these radio buttons, but that's another question). When I try to do this (yes, i'm using haml):

```
    - for foo in @foos
```

I get this error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

My assumption is that this is caused because the @foos collection is empty. What is the proper way to get access to this collection within my user view?

** edit **

I think my initial question was a bit confusing. the first issue i'm trying to figure out is how to access a collection of foos from within my user view. the relationship doesn't matter. I just want a list of all foos in the system. not just the ones assigned to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have `belongs_to :user` in your Foo class?

What does your controller code look like? To show all foos it should have something like this:

```
def index
  @foos = Foo.all
end
```

Comment: I did not have that in my foo model. Now that I've added it, I get this error:

Could not find the association :user_foo in model User

In my foo model, should it be belongs_to :user_foo then in the user_foo should it say belongs_to :foo ? that doesn't seem right either

Comment: ok, so i figured out that i was also missing has_many :foo in my user model. so now i have:

  has_many :user_foo
  has_many :foos, :through => :user_foo

I also needed to add 

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :foo

in my userfoo model. so this solves my xref question.

Comment: but my current issue is that i cannot loop through all foos in the system from the user view. so i guess disregard the whole x-ref thing and look at it like i just want to loop through all foos in the system within my user view.

Comment: Please post the complete User and Foo model code and your controller and view code.

Comment: i found my issue with your help. I needed to setup the has_many and belongs as described above, and i added a foos method in my user model. but the missing items was, I needed to inherit from BaseController instead of ApplicationController for my app.

Comment: It still sounds like there's something weird going on with your app. Your controller classes should inherit from ApplicationController and you shouldn't need to add a foos method to your User model.

Comment: you're correct. the BaseController thing is due to me using CommunityEngine for my site. and i was also able to remove the foos method as well after realizing i had mis-named my controller.

Answer (score 2):

To access all Foos just use

```
@foos = Foo.all
```

in your controller.

The error you were experiencing before, the nil object error could be prevented by a check like:

```
- if @foos.empty?
  %p There are no Foos
- else
  ...
```

Also, the best way to iterate over a collection is by using the `#each` method, not a `for` loop. For example:

```
- @foos.each do |foo|
  %p= foo.name
```

So a finished example would be:

```
- if @foos.empty?
  %p There are no Foos
- else
  - @foos.each do |foo|
    %p= foo.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests you foo object is empty.

If you want all Foo's connected with the current user object, you use

```
my_user = User.find(1) # finds user with id no. 1
list_of_foos = my_user.foos # finds all foos associated with my_user
```

should work

If you are looking for all foo's, no matter what their association, you use

```
list_of_foos = Foo.find(:all)
```

This might not be up to the Rails syntax that's currently in fashion: it's been a while since I actively did Rails development, but this if I understand the question right, this should help you. Good luck.